# Handling request error

Tags: node.js, http-get

I'm modifying a script that makes request to URLs stored inside CSV file. Some of the links are broken or they no longer exists. I need to filter out those links so that node would continue on with good links and would not crash. How should I handle this error so that node wouldn't crash? This is a snippet of my code

```
var req = ref.protocol.get(options, function(res) {        
  res.on('data', function(data) {      
    f.write(data);
  }).on('end', function() {
    f.end();
  });
});

req.on('response', function(err) {
  if(err.statusCode == '404') { 
    console.log("Response ", err);
  }
}); 

req.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("This is error ----" + err);
});
req.end();
```

Edit : After fiddling around with the code, I found that Node crashes only on 302 status. It does not seem to have problem with 404.

Comment: Is it because only the `404` is handled on the `response` event? Should probably be an `else` case.

Comment: I have no code in the response event except console.log to output header information. I'm not sure why 404 is fine but 302 ended up - "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error.