# Filtering out 302 response

Tags: node.js, http

This is a question relating to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268296/handling-request-error?noredirect=1#comment39390746_25268296). How do you kill the request if you know the page you are requesting is redirecting to another page? I only want to access pages that are not redirecting. The reason is that some addresses on my address list redirect to another address and node js keeps crashing with "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error at those pages.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Could you follow the "previous post link"? Cuz I don't want to repost the same thing. Thanks.